# Prove or disprove: If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{2}\cdot a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}a_{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}a_{n}$ be a positive series.

**Prove or disprove:**
If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{2}\cdot a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}a_{n}$ converges.

Could anyone help with some intuition?

I have tried looking for another series; Obviously $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}n^{2}\cdot a_{n}$ diverges but that doesn't really help. I've also tried proving using contradiction but I got stuck as well.

Would appreciate a hint!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test with $b_n = 1/n^2$ ...

Comment: Hint: Convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: @MartinR not sure why I missed that. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have not changed the formatting of the title, which should [take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.